# Undefined variable: position

Tags: php, ajax, variables, undefined

Sorry guys, I am reading and searching over the web and I cannot find a solution for this :(.
If you can please help me :) Thanks.

If I hard code **position** then it works well. I already tried this on several different ways...

P.S.
   I have to create some kind of image gallery ajax page for exercise :) I assume this **position** variable should be in singleton/static class i guess. I was not able to test this class yet, but I think this will work only for first and last image always :) (in java code this would be very easy to do :) ).

Error:
 **Notice: Undefined variable: position in D:\Wamp\www\test\gethint.php on line 11**

```
<?php

class Index {
    private $position=1;

    public function next(){
        return $position++;;
    }

    public function prev(){
        return $position--;
    }

     public function reset(){
        $position=1;
        return $position;
    }
}

$action=$_REQUEST["action"];
    $index = 0;

if($action!=1){
    $index=Index::prev();
} else {
    $index=Index::next();
}

if($index < 1){
    $index=7;
}
if($index > 7){
    $index=1;
}

    $response="<img border=\"0\" src=\"".$index.".jpg\" alt=\"".$index."\" width=\"500\" height=\"334\">";

 echo $response;
 ?>
```

Comment: line 11 or 7 depends on which link i click. I guess in reset is the same (did not test it yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line

```
return $position++;;
```

to

```
return $position++; // extra ;
```

and access class variable like this

```
$this->position++; // not $position
```

for creating static variable  use `static` keyword

```
private static $position=1;
```

for accessing static variable  use

```
self::$position;
```

change this

```
if($action!=1){
    $index=Index::prev();
} else {
    $index=Index::next();
}
```

to

```
$in = new Index();
if($action!=1){
    $index= $in->prev();
} else {
    $index= $in->next();
}
```

Comment: yes but wont work correctly :( I did exactly the same thing :(.
Maybe I should ass index.php as well?

Comment: There is alway first image displayed. I have a feeling that position is initialize each time when I click on a link which call function to load an image. 
`class Index {
 private static $position=1;
    
 public function next(){
  return self::$position++;
    }
 
 public function prev(){
  return self::$position--;
 }
 
  public function reset(){
  self::$position=1;
  return self::$position;
 }
}`

Comment: I will die before I will switch from java to php. I was forced to go from c++ to java several years ago now again to learn new language:S which is very close to c++. :(

any way I tried this with dynamic and static object and always equal result, only first image is alway shown :(.

I will recheck if there is an error in this " complex" logic :(.

P.S.
how to add code to comments?

Comment: I changed some code and now 2nd and last image are shown.
Change:
´ public function next(){
  return self::$position+=1;
    }
 
 public function prev(){
  return self::$position-=1;
 }
´

Comment: use this code http://codepad.org/XnabDhhH **OR** see edited code. you haven't initialised the class. :)

Comment: Please take a look, I have no more ideas :(
[file 1](http://codepad.org/344ztGtU)

[file 2](http://codepad.org/7JmtQ76M)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Index {
    private $position=1;

    public function next(){
        return $this->position++;
    }

    public function prev(){
        return $this->position--;
    }

     public function reset(){
        $this->position=1;
        return $this->position;
    }
}
```

You have to get the class variable, not the local variable ;)

And the reset method worked because you would set the local variable to 1 and then return it, in both other methods the $position variable would be undefined.

Comment: Can I not directly access variables in classes, like in java? Do I need always to use ++this++ keyword?

Comment: @ojc Yes you have to use `$this` keyword for every class variable in `PHP`. But I think also in java you have to use `this` keyword to access class variable.

Comment: in java:
public class X{
 private int x=0;
 
 public void foo(){
  x++;//is fine
 }

 public int foo2(int x){
  return this.x + x;//2st is a class varaibla 2nd is parametr's variable
 }

 public int foo3(int x){
  return x+x;//this will add warning that we probably want to use  this.x and not x.
 }


bes regards.

}

Answer (score 0):

You have this `$position++;;` in next function for `Index` class that should be `$position++;` and to access class property you should use $this.

So use it as `$this->position++;`

Comment: Thx guys it works :) and now I have next problem, like I said I will need to use singleton pattern or static :)